# How to refer to the last seen activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context

I have several activities A,B, C
I have a method isOnline in class D which creates dialog (always same).
From activities A/B/C i am calling isOnline.
Is it possible to find activity which called isOnline purely in class D without sending object from A/B/C to D?

Comment: on a side note it sounds like you are trying to detect if the internet connection is there or not. This library will do it: https://github.com/novoda/merlin

Comment: a trick is to fillstacktrace an check the caller this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there anything wrong with passing in a reference to the activity?

```
public boolean isOnline(Activity a) {
    // ...
}
```

You could pass in anything really, perhaps just the name of the Activity (or some other unique identifier):

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

    void someMethod() {
        OtherClass.isOnline(TAG);
    }
}
```

```
public boolean isOnline(String tag) {
    // inspect TAG
}
```

Comment: really nothing wrong. I just decided to implement network connection before any network operation is fired, so i am lasy to update every class for that purpose. Hoped there is some universal reference.

Comment: Make a BaseActivity class that all your other activities extend and put `isOnline()` in there.